# Can a minor get a copyright registered in India?

Tags: copyright, india

Can a person below 18 register copyright in India?

Comment: Does India have a concept of "registering copyright"? I always thought that's something specific to USA. We know no such thing in Europe's law.

Comment: @ planetmaker [WIPO](https://www.wipo.int/copyright/en/) says: "Most countries nonetheless have a system in place to allow for the voluntary registration of works. Such voluntary registration systems can help solve disputes over ownership or creation, as well as facilitate financial transactions, sales, and the assignment and/or transfer of rights." India has copyright registration,

Answer (score 3):

I have found no evidence to suggest that a citizen under the age of 18 can't hold, or register for copyright in India.

- The copyright rules (http://copyright.gov.in/Copyright_Rules_2013/index.html) do not seem to impose any restrictions which would prevent persons of any certain age from holding a copyright.
- The e-registration page (http://copyright.gov.in/UserRegistration/frmLoginPage.aspx) for registering a copyright does not seem to impose any age requirements, but it does require the person to setup an account. The account registration page (http://copyright.gov.in/UserRegistration/frmNewUser.aspx) does not seem to impose any age requirements. The site terms of use (http://copyright.gov.in/termsCondition.aspx) do not seem to impose any age restrictions for using the site or it's services.
- The registration form "Application Form for Registration of Copyright (Form-XIV)" (http://copyright.gov.in/frmformsDownload.aspx) does not seem to impose any age requirements.